# Cannot execute mysql store procedure with out parameter in asp.net

Tags: asp.net, mysql, stored-procedures

I have this store procedure with out parameter

```
    DELIMITER $$

CREATE DEFINER=`root`@`localhost` PROCEDURE `usp_count_rows`(OUT total int)  
BEGIN
    SELECT COUNT(*)   
    FROM address_book.persons;  
END
```

I want to use it in asp.net page. I write this code behind:

```
        string commandText = "usp_count_rows";
    MySqlConnection conn = new MySqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["mySqlString"].ConnectionString);
    MySqlCommand cmd = null;

    try
    {

        cmd = new MySqlCommand(commandText, conn);
        cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;

        cmd.Parameters.Add("total", MySqlDbType.Int32);
        cmd.Parameters["total"].Direction = ParameterDirection.Output;

        conn.Open();
        cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
        int total = (int)cmd.Parameters["?total"].Value;

    }
    catch (MySqlException ex)
    {
        MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
    }
    finally
    {
        conn.Clone();
    }
```

and i got this error message

> Specified cast is not valid.

fot the line

> int total = (int)cmd.Parameters["?total"].Value;

What should I do to make the code work. And another thing I want ot use the result in aspx page. Something like this: Total number of rows: (result from store procedure). Do you have some suggestions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is happening because your SP doesn't return any parameters, just result of the query. And for a stored procedure like this you do not need any parameters - even output ones, so redefine your SP simple as

```
CREATE DEFINER=`root`@`localhost` PROCEDURE `usp_count_rows`
BEGIN
    SELECT COUNT(*)   
    FROM address_book.persons;  
END
```

Then in you C# get rid of lines (remove them completely):

```
cmd.Parameters.Add("total", MySqlDbType.Int32);
cmd.Parameters["total"].Direction = ParameterDirection.Output;
```

and replace these lines:

```
cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
int total = (int)cmd.Parameters["?total"].Value;
```

with this one line:

```
int total = Convert.ToInt32(cmd.ExecuteScalar());
```

[ExecuteScalar](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlcommand.executescalar.aspx) method executes your SP/Query and returns first column of first row of that query (in your case it will be the only column and the only row with the Count(*)).

Oh by the way in your Finally block it should be conn.Close() not conn.Clone(), but I think it's simple a type.

As for displaying results on the ASPX page - there're multiple ways depending on where and how you want to display it. For example you can add a Label control to your page and execute something like:

```
Label1.Text = "Total number of rows: " + total.ToString();
```

Comment: Can you verify what is the result of query/sp if you run it by itself, outside of code?

Comment: Also, just a thought but perhaps direct cast from Object result of ExecuteScalar to int is not possible, try `int total = Convert.ToInt32(cmd.ExecuteScalar());` instead. I've updated my answer with this line

Comment: When I run the store procedure in MySQL i get the number 12. I tried something else, maybe is not so cleaver but now works.   object total = (object)cmd.ExecuteScalar();

Comment: I've updated my answer, try the `Convert.ToInt32` approach. Also, if you intend this number only for display - assign it to a string variable this way you will avoid double convertion (to Int and later to String). If possible try not to use Object variables

Comment: Yes, this time it runs. This is now the correct answer. Thank you for helping me :)